# App closing on button click

Tags: android, buttonclick

My app is trying to make some calculations and checking for a condition and printing the array of numbers which satisfy the condition.But the app is closing on click.Please help..

```
package com.example.ganesha.app1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button result;
    private EditText cap,pwfac,dis,solution;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resbut);
        cap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capacity);
        pwfac = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.powerfactor);
        dis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance);
        solution = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
        //mytextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result)

        result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            Double capacity = Double.valueOf(cap.getText().toString());
            Double powerfactor = Double.valueOf(pwfac.getText().toString());
            Double distance = Double.valueOf(dis.getText().toString());
            Double amps = capacity / (718.80 * powerfactor);
            Double minimum = 24.9;
            Double ampspermtr=amps/distance;
            Double[] cases = {26.8156, 16.4013, 10.2083, 6.8180, 4.0509, 2.5470, 1.6151, 1.1689, 0.8673, 0.6075, 0.4458, 0.3616, 0.3028, 0.2532, 0.2082, 0.1812, 0.1604, 0.1461, 0.1359};
            Double [] volts=new Double[19];
            for(int i = 0; i <19; i++)
            {
                volts[i]=cases[i]*ampspermtr;
            }

            Double [] wires={1.50,2.50,4.0,6.0,10.0,16.0,25.0,35.0,50.0,70.0,95.0,120.0,150.0,185.0,240.0,300.0,400.0,500.0,630.0};
            final Double [] allpossible = new Double[19];
            int c=0;
            for(int j=0;j<19;j++)
            {
                if(volts[j]<minimum)
                {
                    allpossible[c]=wires[j];

                }
                c++;
            }
            final int g= c;

            for(int p=0;p<g;p++)
            {
               String value = Double.toString(allpossible[g]);
               solution.append(value);
            }
        }
    });
```

It is based on electrical Engineering.Can someone find the mistake and help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

> Actually there some Exception occurred in you calculation in
>   `OnClick` of `Button` you should write the Calculation code surround
>   with `try catch` block like Below

```
try{
Double capacity = Double.valueOf(cap.getText().toString());
            Double powerfactor = Double.valueOf(pwfac.getText().toString());
            Double distance = Double.valueOf(dis.getText().toString());
            Double amps = capacity / (718.80 * powerfactor);
            Double minimum = 24.9;
            Double ampspermtr=amps/distance;
            Double[] cases = {26.8156, 16.4013, 10.2083, 6.8180, 4.0509, 2.5470, 1.6151, 1.1689, 0.8673, 0.6075, 0.4458, 0.3616, 0.3028, 0.2532, 0.2082, 0.1812, 0.1604, 0.1461, 0.1359};
            Double [] volts=new Double[19];
            for(int i = 0; i <19; i++)
            {
                volts[i]=cases[i]*ampspermtr;

            }
            Double [] wires={1.50,2.50,4.0,6.0,10.0,16.0,25.0,35.0,50.0,70.0,95.0,120.0,150.0,185.0,240.0,300.0,400.0,500.0,630.0};
            final Double [] allpossible = new Double[19];
            int c=0;
            for(int j=0;j<19;j++)
            {
                if(volts[j]<minimum)
                {
                    allpossible[c]=wires[j];

                }
                c++;
            }
            final int g= c;

            for(int p=0;p<g;p++)
         {

             String value = Double.toString(allpossible[g]);
             solution.append(value);
         }
        }

}Catch(Exception ex){
// handle your Exception here
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps, but rather ignores the issue.

Comment: it will overcome your force close issue but you have to handle the exception on OnClick

Comment: It has its benefits yes. But I still wonder why its crashing in the first place

Comment: u mean at this line...Double capacity = Double.valueOf(cap.getText().toString());?

Comment: Quite possibly. +1 . Should include in answer, to check the values exist and are valie doubles, before converting to double.